# Reading from mainframe terminal through Node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, mainframe

I have a task at my hand which involves logging in to Mainframe, providing username/password and then reading the response.

Does there exist and npm module to achieve this? I have heard of something called `tn3270` but I am not entirely sure what it is. My guess is that I would be needing two different modules: one to open the terminal and the other one to emulate manual actions on the terminal, like entering text and reading text( Very similar to what Selenium does on Browser)

I am unable to find the appropriate modules to achieve this. Please help.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The mainframe provides IBM 3270 protocol for connection.

Comment: To meet this requirement you need to know exactly what terminal protocol the mainframe provides. It could be UNIX-style ssh. It could be IBM 3270 protocol (from the days when a green-screen CRT terminal to one of those computers that looked like a walk-in freezer was a big deal). Or what? Please find out more and [edit] your question, and maybe we can help more.

Comment: I confirm that mainframe provides 3270 protocol for connection.

Comment: Then [tn3270](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tn3270#example) may solve your problem. Can you do the same operation on an actual 3270 or an emulator to understand what you need to `write()` to the terminal, and what buffers it sends you in the Observable?

Comment: I'd use an SSH connection and stay away from TN3270.  I think this then puts your application on a par with distributed development.

Comment: does mainframe supports ssh? In the project that I have, the driver is picking the text from the mainframe terminal in this format: ``this.terminalDriver.getfieldValue(row, col, length)``

Comment: Assuming this is z/OS yes it supports SSH.  However, it sounds like the application you are accessing is 3270 based  so you would need a different methodology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Node [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module for this. The specifics of how to use it will vary depending on whether you're on Windows or not, but you'll most likely want to use the `exec(command[, options][, callback])` method.